# Generate digital XML signature for large XML file

Tags: c#, java, xml

I am working on one application which gives large XML as output. This XML is almost 3-4 GB in size. I need to sign this XML to make it secure. I'm facing out of memory issue even if i try it on 64 bit machine, with Microsoft framework 4.5 large object support.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: XML was never meant for that amount of data. Maybe you can use another file format and another signature mechanism?

Comment: I agree but this is specific requirement where we must have to end the out put in form of XML only. If we won't use the XML it is against the standard schema.

Comment: If I store the XML as something XYZ extension and then use it as simple file then do you have solution for other file type?

Answer (score 0):

XML has multiple issues when the size is huge.
You can try this [GIT project](https://github.com/learningequality/ka-lite/pull/596), i have not tried this myself.

In my project i have encrypted the xml file using cbc encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It *should* be possible to calculate the XML signature using an event or pull parser rather than having to load the whole document into memory at once. Go looking for a SAX-based XML Signature implementation.

Comment: Is it java based solution or c#.net base?